# Parsing JSON with Erlang (erlang-rfc4627 lib)

Tags: json, parsing, erlang

I am attempting to get some JSON parsed with [erlang-rfc4627](https://github.com/tonyg/erlang-rfc4627) and struggling with the returned results

This is the JSON:

```
{
  "people": [
    {"name": "Toby"}
  ]
}
```

Using the erlang-rfc4627 library:

```
{ok, Json, []} = rfc4627:decode("...")
```

I can decode fine into Erlang as:

```
{obj,[
  {"people",[
    {obj,[
      {"name",<<"Toby">>}
    ]},
    {obj,[
      {"name",<<"Blah">>}
    ]}
  ]}
]}
```

But then what happens?
How do I get an array of people out of this structure in an easy way?
(This is a very simplified model of the overall JSON).

Is there a better library I should be using for this?

**Updated** 
I noticed that when pulling out arrays, each element of the arrays has the *awful* obj structure wrapped into it, which makes the process of manipulating arrays very clumsy.

Why on earth is this so complex in Erlang?

Reference: http://www.lshift.net/blog/2007/02/17/json-and-json-rpc-for-erlang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
lookup(K, {obj, PL}) -> proplists:get_value(K, PL).
```

And then

```
People = lookup("people", JSON),
Names  = [lookup("name", Obj) || Obj <- People].
```

The better way generalizes this idea into a query-compiler which can compile any query to a function which can then be applied to a JSON document. It will be way easier should you want to to rumaging inside JSON documents all the time.

It is also important to note that you should probably not be operating directly on the JSON structure, but embed it in something else inside the Erlang world.

Comment: https://github.com/etrepum/kvc does such queries but it doesn't currently support {obj, proplist()}. Would be a trivial patch, though.

Comment: Yeah, I definitely don't want to be diving into JSON, but would like to convert to something I can do useful things with inside my Erlang app.

Comment: There are no arrays, only lists. Even the `array` module cheats and uses trees internally.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better library I should be using for this?

Please, try use library like [jiffy](https://github.com/davisp/jiffy), because this library is easy to use:

```
1> Doc = {[{foo, [<<"bing">>, 2.3, true]}]}.
{[{foo,[<<"bing">>,2.3,true]}]}
2> BinJSON = jiffy:encode(Doc).
<<"{\"foo\":[\"bing\",2.3,true]}">>
3> JsonMap = jiffy:decode(BinJSON, [return_maps]).
#{<<"foo">> => [<<"bing">>,2.3,true]}
4> maps:get(<<"foo">>, JsonMap, undefined).
[<<"bing">>,2.3,true]
```